# cd: can't cd to /mnt/c/Program

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, bash, bash-scripting

How should I fix this error? I am using "Bash On Ubuntu On Windows" in Windows 10 to run it:

```
mona@DESKTOP-37GGNHL:/mnt/c/Users/mona/baldurk/renderdoc/renderdocui/3rdparty/ironpython$ ./output.sh /mnt/c/"Program Files (x86)"/"IronPython 2.7"
./output.sh: 8: cd: can't cd to /mnt/c/Program
./output.sh: 9: ./output.sh: zip: not found
mona@DESKTOP-37GGNHL:/mnt/c/Users/mona/baldurk/renderdoc/renderdocui/3rdparty/ironpython$ cat output.sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 /path/to/IronPython/";
        exit;
fi
IRONPYTHON="$1"
OUTDIR=$PWD
cd $IRONPYTHON/Lib
zip -r $OUTDIR/pythonlibs.zip *
```

Update:

```
mona@DESKTOP-37GGNHL:/mnt/c/Users/mona/baldurk/renderdoc/renderdocui/3rdparty/ironpython$ ./output.sh "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/IronPython 2.7"
./output.sh: 8: cd: can't cd to /mnt/c/Program
updating: IronPython.Modules.dll (deflated 62%)
updating: IronPython.Modules.xml (deflated 85%)
updating: IronPython.dll (deflated 58%)
updating: IronPython.xml (deflated 83%)
updating: LICENSE.md (deflated 64%)
updating: Microsoft.Dynamic.dll (deflated 64%)
updating: Microsoft.Dynamic.xml (deflated 84%)
updating: Microsoft.Scripting.dll (deflated 58%)
updating: Microsoft.Scripting.xml (deflated 88%)
updating: README.md (deflated 41%)
updating: compilelibs.sh (deflated 13%)
updating: output.sh (deflated 12%)
mona@DESKTOP-37GGNHL:/mnt/c/Users/mona/baldurk/renderdoc/renderdocui/3rdparty/ironpython$ cat output.sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 /path/to/IronPython/";
        exit;
fi
IRONPYTHON="$1"
OUTDIR=$PWD
cd $IRONPYTHON/Lib
zip -r $OUTDIR/pythonlibs.zip *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 8 to the following:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 /path/to/IronPython/";
        exit;
fi
IRONPYTHON="$1"
OUTDIR=$PWD
cd "$IRONPYTHON/Lib"
zip -r $OUTDIR/pythonlibs.zip *
```

You will get the following output:

```
mona@DESKTOP-37GGNHL:/mnt/c/Users/mona/baldurk/renderdoc/renderdocui/3rdparty/ironpython$ ./output.sh "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/IronPython 2.7"
  adding: BaseHTTPServer.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: Bastion.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: CGIHTTPServer.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: ConfigParser.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: Cookie.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: DocXMLRPCServer.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: HTMLParser.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: MimeWriter.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: Queue.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: SimpleHTTPServer.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: SimpleXMLRPCServer.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: SocketServer.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: StringIO.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: UserDict.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: UserList.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: UserString.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: _LWPCookieJar.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: _MozillaCookieJar.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: __future__.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: __phello__.foo.py (deflated 3%)
  adding: _abcoll.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: _pyio.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: _strptime.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: _threading_local.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: _weakrefset.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: abc.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: aifc.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: antigravity.py (deflated 11%)
  adding: anydbm.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: argparse.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: ast.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: asynchat.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: asyncore.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: atexit.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: audiodev.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: base64.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: bdb.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: binhex.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: bisect.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: calendar.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: cgi.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: cgitb.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: chunk.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: cmd.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: code.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: codecs.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: codeop.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: collections.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: colorsys.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: commands.py (deflated 58%)
  adding: compileall.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: contextlib.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: cookielib.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: copy.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: csv.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: ctypes/ (stored 0%)
  adding: ctypes/macholib/ (stored 0%)
  adding: ctypes/macholib/dyld.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: ctypes/macholib/dylib.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: ctypes/macholib/framework.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: ctypes/macholib/__init__.py (deflated 48%)
  adding: ctypes/util.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: ctypes/wintypes.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: ctypes/_endian.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: ctypes/__init__.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: decimal.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: difflib.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: dircache.py (deflated 53%)
  adding: dis.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: distutils/ (stored 0%)
  adding: distutils/archive_util.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: distutils/bcppcompiler.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: distutils/ccompiler.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: distutils/cmd.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: distutils/command/ (stored 0%)
  adding: distutils/command/bdist.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/command/bdist_dumb.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: distutils/command/bdist_rpm.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: distutils/command/bdist_wininst.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: distutils/command/build.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: distutils/command/build_clib.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: distutils/command/build_ext.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: distutils/command/build_py.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: distutils/command/build_scripts.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/command/check.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/command/clean.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/command/config.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: distutils/command/install.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: distutils/command/install_data.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/command/install_egg_info.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: distutils/command/install_headers.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: distutils/command/install_lib.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: distutils/command/install_scripts.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: distutils/command/register.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: distutils/command/sdist.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: distutils/command/upload.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: distutils/command/__init__.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: distutils/config.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: distutils/core.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: distutils/cygwinccompiler.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: distutils/debug.py (deflated 19%)
  adding: distutils/dep_util.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: distutils/dir_util.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: distutils/dist.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: distutils/emxccompiler.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: distutils/errors.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: distutils/extension.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/fancy_getopt.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: distutils/filelist.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: distutils/file_util.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: distutils/log.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: distutils/msvccompiler.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: distutils/spawn.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/sysconfig.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: distutils/text_file.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: distutils/unixccompiler.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: distutils/util.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: distutils/version.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: distutils/versionpredicate.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: distutils/__init__.py (deflated 37%)
  adding: doctest.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: dumbdbm.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: dummy_thread.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: dummy_threading.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: email/ (stored 0%)
  adding: email/base64mime.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: email/charset.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: email/encoders.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: email/errors.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: email/feedparser.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: email/generator.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: email/header.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: email/iterators.py (deflated 59%)
  adding: email/message.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: email/mime/ (stored 0%)
  adding: email/mime/application.py (deflated 55%)
  adding: email/mime/audio.py (deflated 56%)
  adding: email/mime/base.py (deflated 50%)
  adding: email/mime/image.py (deflated 56%)
  adding: email/mime/message.py (deflated 53%)
  adding: email/mime/multipart.py (deflated 57%)
  adding: email/mime/nonmultipart.py (deflated 46%)
  adding: email/mime/text.py (deflated 51%)
  adding: email/mime/__init__.py (stored 0%)
  adding: email/parser.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: email/quoprimime.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: email/utils.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: email/_parseaddr.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: email/__init__.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: encodings/ (stored 0%)
  adding: encodings/aliases.py (deflated 81%)
  adding: encodings/ascii.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: encodings/base64_codec.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: encodings/bz2_codec.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: encodings/charmap.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: encodings/cp037.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp1006.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/cp1026.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp1140.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp1250.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/cp1251.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/cp1252.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp1253.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp1254.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp1255.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: encodings/cp1256.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: encodings/cp1257.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp1258.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp424.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: encodings/cp437.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp500.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp720.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/cp737.py (deflated 81%)
  adding: encodings/cp775.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp850.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp852.py (deflated 81%)
  adding: encodings/cp855.py (deflated 81%)
  adding: encodings/cp856.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp857.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp858.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp860.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp861.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp862.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp863.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp864.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp865.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp866.py (deflated 81%)
  adding: encodings/cp869.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/cp874.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/cp875.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/hex_codec.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: encodings/hp_roman8.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: encodings/idna.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_1.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_10.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_11.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_13.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_14.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_15.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_16.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_2.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_3.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_4.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_5.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_6.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_7.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_8.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: encodings/iso8859_9.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/koi8_r.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/koi8_u.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/latin_1.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: encodings/mac_arabic.py (deflated 83%)
  adding: encodings/mac_centeuro.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/mac_croatian.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/mac_cyrillic.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/mac_farsi.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/mac_greek.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/mac_iceland.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/mac_latin2.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/mac_roman.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/mac_romanian.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/mac_turkish.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: encodings/mbcs.py (deflated 57%)
  adding: encodings/palmos.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: encodings/ptcp154.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: encodings/punycode.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: encodings/quopri_codec.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: encodings/raw_unicode_escape.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: encodings/rot_13.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: encodings/string_escape.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: encodings/tis_620.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: encodings/undefined.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: encodings/unicode_escape.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: encodings/unicode_internal.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: encodings/utf_16.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: encodings/utf_16_be.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: encodings/utf_16_le.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: encodings/utf_32.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: encodings/utf_32_le.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: encodings/utf_7.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: encodings/utf_8.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: encodings/utf_8_sig.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: encodings/uu_codec.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: encodings/zlib_codec.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: encodings/__init__.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: ensurepip/ (stored 0%)
  adding: ensurepip/_bundled/ (stored 0%)
  adding: ensurepip/_bundled/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (deflated 3%)
  adding: ensurepip/_bundled/setuptools-3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (deflated 2%)
  adding: ensurepip/_uninstall.py (deflated 53%)
  adding: ensurepip/__init__.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: ensurepip/__main__.py (deflated 14%)
  adding: filecmp.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: fileinput.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: fnmatch.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: formatter.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: fpformat.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: fractions.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: ftplib.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: functools.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: genericpath.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: getopt.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: getpass.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: gettext.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: glob.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: gzip.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: hashlib.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: heapq.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: hmac.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: htmlentitydefs.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: htmllib.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: httplib.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: ihooks.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: imaplib.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: imghdr.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: importlib/ (stored 0%)
  adding: importlib/__init__.py (deflated 55%)
  adding: imputil.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: inspect.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: io.py (deflated 58%)
  adding: json/ (stored 0%)
  adding: json/decoder.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: json/encoder.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: json/scanner.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: json/tool.py (deflated 55%)
  adding: json/__init__.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: keyword.py (deflated 59%)
  adding: lib2to3/ (stored 0%)
  adding: lib2to3/btm_matcher.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: lib2to3/btm_utils.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixer_base.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixer_util.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/ (stored 0%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_apply.py (deflated 59%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_basestring.py (deflated 36%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_buffer.py (deflated 39%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_callable.py (deflated 49%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_dict.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_except.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_exec.py (deflated 50%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_execfile.py (deflated 59%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_exitfunc.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_filter.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_funcattrs.py (deflated 47%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_future.py (deflated 41%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_getcwdu.py (deflated 40%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_has_key.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_idioms.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_import.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_imports.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_imports2.py (deflated 39%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_input.py (deflated 46%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_intern.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_isinstance.py (deflated 57%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_itertools.py (deflated 58%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_itertools_imports.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_long.py (deflated 38%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_map.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_metaclass.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_methodattrs.py (deflated 44%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_ne.py (deflated 41%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_next.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_nonzero.py (deflated 47%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_numliterals.py (deflated 45%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_operator.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_paren.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_print.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_raise.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_raw_input.py (deflated 40%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_reduce.py (deflated 56%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_renames.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_repr.py (deflated 41%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_set_literal.py (deflated 59%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_standarderror.py (deflated 38%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_sys_exc.py (deflated 51%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_throw.py (deflated 57%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_tuple_params.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_types.py (deflated 55%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_unicode.py (deflated 50%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_urllib.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_ws_comma.py (deflated 57%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_xrange.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_xreadlines.py (deflated 49%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/fix_zip.py (deflated 48%)
  adding: lib2to3/fixes/__init__.py (stored 0%)
  adding: lib2to3/main.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: lib2to3/patcomp.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/conv.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/driver.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/grammar.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/literals.py (deflated 59%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/parse.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/pgen.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/token.py (deflated 49%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/tokenize.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: lib2to3/pgen2/__init__.py (deflated 12%)
  adding: lib2to3/pygram.py (deflated 56%)
  adding: lib2to3/pytree.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: lib2to3/refactor.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: lib2to3/__init__.py (stored 0%)
  adding: lib2to3/__main__.py (deflated 11%)
  adding: linecache.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: locale.py (deflated 81%)
  adding: logging/ (stored 0%)
  adding: logging/config.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: logging/handlers.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: logging/__init__.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: macpath.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: macurl2path.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: mailbox.py (deflated 82%)
  adding: mailcap.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: markupbase.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: md5.py (deflated 31%)
  adding: mhlib.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: mimetools.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: mimetypes.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: mimify.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: modulefinder.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: multifile.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: multiprocessing/ (stored 0%)
  adding: multiprocessing/connection.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: multiprocessing/dummy/ (stored 0%)
  adding: multiprocessing/dummy/connection.py (deflated 55%)
  adding: multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: multiprocessing/forking.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: multiprocessing/heap.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: multiprocessing/managers.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: multiprocessing/pool.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: multiprocessing/process.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: multiprocessing/queues.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: multiprocessing/reduction.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: multiprocessing/synchronize.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: multiprocessing/util.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: multiprocessing/__init__.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: mutex.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: netrc.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: new.py (deflated 50%)
  adding: nntplib.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: ntpath.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: nturl2path.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: numbers.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: opcode.py (deflated 67%)
  adding: optparse.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: os.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: os2emxpath.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: pdb.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: pickle.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: pickletools.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: pipes.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: pkgutil.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: platform.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: plistlib.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: popen2.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: poplib.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: posixfile.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: posixpath.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: pprint.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: profile.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: pstats.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: py_compile.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: pyclbr.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: pydoc.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: pydoc_data/ (stored 0%)
  adding: pydoc_data/topics.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: pydoc_data/__init__.py (stored 0%)
  adding: quopri.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: random.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: repr.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: rexec.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: rfc822.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: rlcompleter.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: robotparser.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: runpy.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: sched.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: sets.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: sgmllib.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: sha.py (deflated 35%)
  adding: shelve.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: shlex.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: shutil.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: site-packages/ (stored 0%)
  adding: site-packages/README.txt (deflated 18%)
  adding: site.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: smtpd.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: smtplib.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: sndhdr.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: sqlite3/ (stored 0%)
  adding: sqlite3/dbapi2.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: sqlite3/dump.py (deflated 60%)
  adding: sqlite3/__init__.py (deflated 46%)
  adding: sre_compile.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: sre_constants.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: sre_parse.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: ssl.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: stat.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: statvfs.py (deflated 54%)
  adding: string.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: stringold.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: stringprep.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: struct.py (deflated 42%)
  adding: subprocess.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: sunau.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: sunaudio.py (deflated 59%)
  adding: symbol.py (deflated 55%)
  adding: sysconfig.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: tabnanny.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: tarfile.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: telnetlib.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: tempfile.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: textwrap.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: this.py (deflated 46%)
  adding: threading.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: timeit.py (deflated 66%)
  adding: toaiff.py (deflated 63%)
  adding: token.py (deflated 57%)
  adding: tokenize.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: trace.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: traceback.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: types.py (deflated 55%)
  adding: unittest/ (stored 0%)
  adding: unittest/case.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: unittest/loader.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: unittest/main.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: unittest/result.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: unittest/runner.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: unittest/signals.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: unittest/suite.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: unittest/util.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: unittest/__init__.py (deflated 52%)
  adding: unittest/__main__.py (deflated 30%)
  adding: urllib.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: urllib2.py (deflated 72%)
  adding: urlparse.py (deflated 70%)
  adding: user.py (deflated 52%)
  adding: uu.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: uuid.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: warnings.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: wave.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: weakref.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: webbrowser.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: whichdb.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: wsgiref/ (stored 0%)
  adding: wsgiref/handlers.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: wsgiref/headers.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: wsgiref/simple_server.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: wsgiref/util.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: wsgiref/validate.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: wsgiref/__init__.py (deflated 43%)
  adding: xdrlib.py (deflated 76%)
  adding: xml/ (stored 0%)
  adding: xml/dom/ (stored 0%)
  adding: xml/dom/domreg.py (deflated 64%)
  adding: xml/dom/minicompat.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: xml/dom/minidom.py (deflated 80%)
  adding: xml/dom/NodeFilter.py (deflated 61%)
  adding: xml/dom/pulldom.py (deflated 78%)
  adding: xml/dom/xmlbuilder.py (deflated 75%)
  adding: xml/dom/__init__.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: xml/etree/ (stored 0%)
  adding: xml/etree/ElementInclude.py (deflated 62%)
  adding: xml/etree/ElementPath.py (deflated 69%)
  adding: xml/etree/ElementTree.py (deflated 77%)
  adding: xml/etree/SimpleXMLTreeBuilder.py (deflated 57%)
  adding: xml/etree/__init__.py (deflated 48%)
  adding: xml/parsers/ (stored 0%)
  adding: xml/parsers/__init__.py (deflated 22%)
  adding: xml/sax/ (stored 0%)
  adding: xml/sax/handler.py (deflated 73%)
  adding: xml/sax/saxutils.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: xml/sax/xmlreader.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: xml/sax/_exceptions.py (deflated 68%)
  adding: xml/sax/__init__.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: xml/__init__.py (deflated 48%)
  adding: xmllib.py (deflated 79%)
  adding: xmlrpclib.py (deflated 74%)
  adding: zipfile.py (deflated 75%)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem almost certainly has to do with the interpretation of spaces.  I would thus do 2 things:

1. I'd modify the program to insert a second line that the second line reads IFS=$'\n'    This will mean that the delimeter character is now newline rather then space.
2. I would call the program differently - escaping the " " character using

> ./output.sh /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/IronPython\ 2.7